# Nginx: Serve static files for a subpath

Tags: nginx

[**UPDATE/Note:** "subdomain" in the following description actually means a *subpath* in the URL, sorry for the confusion. I changed the title but left the description as it was.]

I would like to serve static content from a subdomain:

```
location /subdomain/ {
    root /www/mydirectory;
    index  index.html;

    client_max_body_size 10g;
}
```

The problem is that the `index.html` for `https://mydomain/mysubdomain/` then has to be available in directory `/www/mydirectory/mysuddomain`, but I would like to place it into `/www/mydirectory`. In other words: When using the URL `https://mydomain/mysuddomain/`, then `/www/mydirectory/mysuddomain/index.html` is served, but it should be `/www/mydirectory/index.html`

Comment: You should use an [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive instead: `alias /www/mydirectory/;` If you'd have `location /subdomain { ... }` (note the absence of trailing slash), then you should use `alias /www/mydirectory;` (without trailing slash too).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, a posted the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the above answer by Ivan Shatsky: I changed to the following and it worked:

```
location /subdomain {
    alias /www/mydirectory;
    index  index.html;

    client_max_body_size 10g;
}
```

(I also noted that other than I thought before, using `/subdomain` i.e. without a trailing slash does not mean that `/subdomain2` also matches.)